# How to use 2 ToggleButton for different 2 Different Alarms

Tags: java, android

i am using 2 toggleButtons for to different alarms as shown in the code , when i Activate anyone of these Button , both alarms works at the same time  , so how can i solve that as i will use more than 2

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    ToggleButton toggleButton , toggleButton1 ;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.togelbutton);
        toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.togelbutton1);

        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmReceiver.class);

                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000*10,pendingIntent);
                }
                else{
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"noti ended",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });

        toggleButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmReceiver.class);

                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),2,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000*10,pendingIntent);
                }
                else{
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"noti ended",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }
}



public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompat;
private static final int uniqueID = 24314;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent ) {

    Toast.makeText(context,"welcome here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    alarm1(context);
    alarm2(context);

}

public void alarm1 (Context context){

    notificationCompat = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    notificationCompat.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationCompat .setTicker("Notification1");
    notificationCompat  .setContentTitle("Notification 1");
    notificationCompat  .setContentText("Good Job");
    notificationCompat  .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationCompat.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    notificationCompat.setVibrate(new long[] {100,2000,100,2000});
    notificationCompat.setLights(Color.BLUE,400,400);


    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationCompat.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(uniqueID,notificationCompat.build());

}

public void alarm2 (Context context){

    notificationCompat = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    notificationCompat.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationCompat .setTicker("Notification2");
    notificationCompat  .setContentTitle("Notification 2");
    notificationCompat  .setContentText("Good Job");
    notificationCompat  .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationCompat.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    notificationCompat.setVibrate(new long[] {100,2000,100,2000});
    notificationCompat.setLights(Color.BLUE,400,400);


    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,2,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationCompat.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(uniqueID,notificationCompat.build());

}
```

}

Comment: Hi. First thing that caught my eye is you are using the same pending intent and overriding it, I'd suggest making it a private field in the checkChanged methods, or, make 2 members as a first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer
is to use shared Preference to save the state of Toggle Buttons then set the alarm or cancel it depend on the status of Toggle Button